# How to draw a diagram for the following PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, laplace-transform, partial-derivative

Subject: Partial Differential Equations.

Here are the details of the question:

$$ \frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial y^2} = 0 $$ 
for $0 < x < 3, 0 < y < 1$

$$u(0, y) = 0,\text{ for }0 ≤ y ≤ 1  $$
$$u(3, y) = 0,\text{  for }0 ≤ y ≤ 1,  $$
$$u(x, 0) = 0,\text{  for }0 < x < 3,  $$
$$u(x, 1) = x(x − 3),\text{  for }0 < x < 3.$$

Let the step size in both the $x$ and the $y$ direction be $h = 0.5$.

Question:

> Make a diagram of the domain and the grid (with step size h) that clearly shows all the information available. Label the grid points and indicate which ones are interior points and which ones are boundary points.

I have come up with the following but I'm not convinced it's correct:

[http://i.imgur.com/MetclnU.png](https://i.imgur.com/MetclnU.png)

Do I need to incorporate $ x(x − 3) $ into the top line of the graph?

Comment: It depends if you are mapping the grid or the value of $u(x,y)$ at the boundary? If it's the latter then it can't be shown on a 2d plot..though I could be wrong.

Comment: Just mapping the grid, sorry I forgot to add in the actual question.

Comment: Then the only thing I would add would be the functional of the "top" boundary, as you would probably mess up the graph, unless you can draw the curve with a separate axis?

Comment: I think I'll just add in the function.